# How to validate FormGroups in a FormArray

Tags: angular

How can I validate each FormGroup in a FormArray? Here I have the custom validator:

```
export class GridProcessorValidator {

  static validateGroupItem(definition: ObjectDefinition) {
      return function(control: AbstractControl): ValidatorFn {
          return null;
      };
  }

}
```

And here is the form:

```
this.gridProcessorForm = this.fb.group({
    propertiesSide: new FormControl(),
    objectNamesSide: new FormControl(),
    groupItems: this.fb.array([], validateGroupItem(this.myCollection))   // array of form groups that needs custom validation
});
```

How can I access the values of FormGroups within the custom validator `definitionPropertiesMatched` so I can check it then print it to the template for individual FormGroups that are invalid?

**Template:**

```
*ngFor="let item of gridProcessorForm.get('groupItems').controls; let i=index"
                    [formGroupName]="i"> ...
```

Then I have form field accessor:

```
{{item.get('propertyName').value}}
```

Is there a way I can get any errors for an item (FormGroup) in the iterator?

Comment: you have to pass array of control name in `this.fb.array([], validateGroupItem(this.myCollection))`  to `this.fb.array([{'controlName' : ' '}], validateGroupItem(this.myCollection))`

Answer (score 1):

If you write

```
this.fb.array([], validateGroupItem(this.myCollection))
```

You're validate the whole formArray, then your validators function can be like

```
static validateGroupItem(definition: ObjectDefinition) {
      return function(control: FormArray): ValidatorFn {
          return null;
      };
  }
```

If you want a validator over each group of your array, you need add the validator when push a formGroup in the array,e.g.

```
createGroup()
{
    return this.fb.group({
      name:''
      surname:''
    },validateGroupItem(this.myCollection))
}
```

And you use

```
this.gridProcessorForm.get('groupItems') as FormArray.push(this.createGroup())
```

Or

```
this.gridProcessorForm = this.fb.group({
    propertiesSide: new FormControl(),
    objectNamesSide: new FormControl(),
    groupItems: this.fb.array([this.createGroup(),this.createGroup()]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your html access each form group state through the loop template input variable, in your case 'item' :

```
   *ngFor="let item of gridProcessorForm.get('groupItems').controls; let i=index"
                    [formGroupName]="i"> 
      ...

   <div *ngIf="item.invalid" class="text-danger"> Invalid !</div> 
      ...
```

Comment: No I want to access the values so I can use the value in the validator class. I need to do this before I use *ngIf="item.invalid". In the validateGroupItem function.